# How do I assign object from one class to another class and how do I calculate double and int inside an ArrayList?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, composition

I have an assignment but i have problem trying to do some part of it. Appreciate if anyone can give me a hand.

Assignment brief: https://pastebin.com/3PiqvfTE

Main Method: https://pastebin.com/J2kFzB3B

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);


        //subject object
        Subject subject = new Subject (0,null,0);
        System.out.println("How many subject do you want to enter: ");
        int subjectNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < subjectNumber; j++) {

            //subject ID
            System.out.println("Please enter the subject ID: ");
            int subID = scanner.nextInt();

            //subject Name
            System.out.println("Please enter subject name: ");
            String subName = scanner.next();

            //subject fee
            System.out.println("Please enter subject fee: ");
            double subFee = scanner.nextDouble();

            //add subject
            subject.addSubject(subID, subName, subFee);
        }

        //display subject
        System.out.println(subject.getSubject());



        /*
        //loop for part time teacher
        System.out.println("Please enter how many part time teacher do you have: ");
        int PTcounter = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < PTcounter; i++) {
        */





        Teacher teach = new Teacher (0,null,null);

        //teacher employee ID
        System.out.println ("Please enter the teacher employee ID: ");
        int tid = scanner.nextInt();

        //teacher name 
        System.out.println("Please enter the teacher name: ");
        String tname = scanner.next();

        //teacher gender
        System.out.println("Please enter the teacher gender: ");
        String tgender = scanner.next();

        //add teacher details
        teach.addTeacher(tid, tname, tgender);

        //display teacher details
        System.out.println(teach.getTeacher());





        //call address class
        Address address = new Address (0,null,null,0);

        //address house number
        System.out.println("Please enter house number: ");
        int addyNum = scanner.nextInt();

        //address street name
        System.out.println("Please enter street name: ");
        String StreetName = scanner.next();

        //address city
        System.out.println("Please enter city: ");
        String City = scanner.next();

        //address post code
        System.out.println("Please enter postcode: ");
        int Postcode = scanner.nextInt();

        //add address
        address.addAddress(addyNum, StreetName, City, Postcode);

        //display address
        System.out.println(address.getAddress());




        //call Part Time Salary class
        PartTimeSalary ptSalary = new PartTimeSalary(0,0);

        //max hours
        System.out.println("Please enter maximum work hours: ");
        int maxHours = scanner.nextInt();

        //hourly rate
        System.out.println("Please enter hourly rate: ");
        double hourlyRate = scanner.nextDouble();

        ptSalary.addPTSalary(maxHours, hourlyRate);

        System.out.println(ptSalary.getHourlyRate());

        //System.out.printf("Teacher details is %s, Subject details is %s, Address is %s", teach.toString(),subject.toString(),address.toString());



    }


}
```

1st problem. I have a subject class and a teacher class. Teacher will be able to teach maximum of 4 subject. I have prompt user to enter subject details before entering teacher details, so when user enter teacher details they will be able to assign subject to teacher just by using the subjectID. I have problem implementing this. My subject is already store in an ArrayList but how to I connect this with teacher. And in the end the program will display what subject each teacher teaches.

Subject Class: https://pastebin.com/iBYFqYDN

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Subject {

    private int subjectID;
    private String subjectName;
    private double fee;
    private ArrayList <Subject> subjectList = new ArrayList <Subject>();

    public Subject(int subjectID, String subjectName, double fee) {
        this.subjectID = subjectID;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    public int getSubjectID () {
        return subjectID;
    }

    public void setSubjectID (int subjectID) {
        this.subjectID = subjectID;
    }

    public String getSubjectName () {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName (String subjectName) {
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public double getFee () {
        return fee;
    }

    public void setFee (double fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[subjectID=" + subjectID + ", subjectName=" + subjectName + ", fee=" + fee + "]";
    }

    public void addSubject (int subjectID, String subjectName, double fee) {
        subjectList.add(new Subject(subjectID, subjectName, fee) );
    }

    public String getSubject () {
        return Arrays.toString(subjectList.toArray());
    }


}
```

Teacher class: https://pastebin.com/Np7xUry2

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Teacher {

    private int employeeID;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private ArrayList <Teacher> teacherDetailsList;

    public Teacher (int employeeID, String name, String gender) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.teacherDetailsList = new ArrayList <Teacher>();
    }

    public int getEmployeeID () {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID (int employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender () {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender (String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[employeeID=" + employeeID + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
    }

    public void addTeacher (int employeeID, String name, String gender) {
        teacherDetailsList.add(new Teacher (employeeID,name,gender));
    }

    public String getTeacher () {
        return Arrays.toString(teacherDetailsList.toArray());
    }
}
```

2nd problem. Teacher will either be part time or full time teacher. Part time teacher will have a maximum work hour they can work and an hourly rate they will be paid for, so the final salary of part time teacher will be "maximum hours" multiply by "hourly rate". I have store "hourly rate" and "maximum work hours" in an ArrayList but how do I call them to make the multiplication then displaying at the end.

Part time salary class: https://pastebin.com/iGKpu87Y

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PartTimeSalary {

    private int maxHour;
    private double hourlyRate;
    private double hourlySalary;
    private ArrayList <PartTimeSalary> PTSalary = new ArrayList <PartTimeSalary>();
    private ArrayList <Double> finalHourlySalary = new ArrayList <Double>();

    public PartTimeSalary (int maxHour, double hourlyRate) {
        this.maxHour = maxHour;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    public int getMaxHours () {
        return maxHour;
    }

    public void setMaxHour (int maxHour) {
        this.maxHour = maxHour;
    }

    public double getHourlyRate () {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setHourlyRate (double hourlyRate) {
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    public double getHourlySalary() {
        hourlySalary = hourlyRate*maxHour;
        return hourlySalary;
    }

    public void addPTSalary (int maxHour, double hourlyRate) {
        PTSalary.add(new PartTimeSalary(maxHour,hourlyRate));
    }


    public void FinalHourlySalary (double hourlySalary) {
        hourlySalary = hourlyRate * maxHour;
        finalHourlySalary.add(hourlySalary);
    }


    public ArrayList<Double> getFinalSalary () {
        return (new ArrayList <Double>());
    }
}
```

3rd question. I have an address class which is suppose to be part of the Teacher class. I can't seem to connect the address class with teacher class.

Address class: https://pastebin.com/s2HN5p80

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Address {

    private int houseNum;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
    private int postcode;
    private List <Address> address = new ArrayList <Address>();

    public Address (int houseNum, String streetName, String city, int postcode) {
        this.houseNum = houseNum;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.city = city;
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public int getHouseNum() {
        return houseNum;
    }

    public void setHouseNum (int houseNum) {
        this.houseNum = houseNum;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public void setStreetName (String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity (String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public int getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode (int postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }


    public void addAddress (int houseNum, String streetName, String city, int postcode) {
        address.add(new Address (houseNum,streetName,city,postcode));
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[houseNum=" + houseNum + ", streetName=" + streetName + ", city=" + city + ", postcode="
                + postcode + "]";
    }

    public String getAddress () {
        return Arrays.toString(address.toArray());
    }


}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1)

- Put the "teacherDetailsList" and "subjectList" ArrayLists in the main method, not the consructors. Add the teachers and subjects in main methods, not constructors.
- Add a new ArrayList called "mySubjects" as a field for the Teacher Class
- Add the following 2 method to the Teacher class:

```
public Teacher (int employeeID, String name, String gender, ArrayList<Subject> s) {
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.mySubjects=s;
}
public Teacher (int employeeID, String name, String gender, Subject s) {
    this.employeeID = employeeID;
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.mySubjects.add(s);
}
public void addSubject(Subject s, boolean b){
    if(mySubjects.size()<4)mySubjects.add(s);
    else throw OutOfBoundsError;
}
public void removeSubject(Subject s, boolean b){
    mySubject.remove(s);
}
public void addSubject(Subject s){
    s.changeTeacher(s);
}
public void removeSubject(Subject s){
    mySubject.remove(s);
}
```

- Add the following methods & fields to Student class

```
private Teacher teacher;
public Subject(int subjectID, String subjectName, double fee, Teacher t) {
    this.subjectID = subjectID;
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
    this.fee = fee;
    this.setTeacher(t);
}
public void setTeacher(Teacher t){
    try{
        t.addSubject(this);
        teacher=t;
    }
    catch(OutOfBoundsError e){
        System.out.println(t.getName()+" already has a full schedule.");
    }
}
public void changeTeacher(Teacher t){
    teacher.removeSubject(this);
    teacher = t;
    t.addSubject(this);
}
```

### Question 2)

- make a new double field, constructor parameter (for every constructor in the class), mutator method and accessor mutator called maxHour in the class Subject
- add a double field to the teacher class called salary. If the teacher is part-time, set this to 0 in the constructor.
- add this method to Teacher class:

```
public double getSalary(){
    if(salary!=0) return salary;
    double s=0;
    for(Subject i: mySubjects) s+=i.getFee()*i.getMaxHours();
    return s;
}
```

- You honestly no longer need the PartTimeSalary class now.

### Question 3

- make a new Address field, constructor parameter (for every constructor in the class), mutator method and accessor mutator called myAddress in the class Teacher
- Don't bother with the ArrayList stuff in your Address Class